# Java Записать в выходной файл слова по одному на строке, без пунктуации

Tags: java, файлы, строки, вывод

Задание: файл 1 перезаписать в файл 2 все слова, но по одному на каждой строке, без какой-либо пунктуации (используя StringTokenizer).

У меня выполнены все пункты задания кроме одного.
Запись в выходной файл.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

public class лаба2 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException 
    {
       String s;
       int l=0;
       BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F:/1.txt"));
       while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
           l++;
           StringTokenizer st; 
           st = new StringTokenizer(s, " \t\n\r,.?");
           while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
               System.out.println(st.nextToken()); 
           }    
       }
    }
}
```

Я не могу догнать, куда вставлять запись файла.

Comment: После считывания из файла 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В чем проблема-то, считываем строку, парсим на токены и сразу пишем в другой файл:

```
//...
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("F:/1.txt"));
Writer wr = new FileWriter("F:/2.txt");
while ((s = in.readLine()) != null) {
    l++;
    StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, " \t\n\r,.?");
    while(st.hasMoreTokens()) {
        wr.write(st.nextToken());
        wr.write(System.lineSeparator()); 
    }    
}
wr.close();  
//...
```